# How to set repeat current media in the Meridian player with adb command?

Tags: android, adb

I want to test power consumption for an android device in play video situation.  The video player is [Meridian Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.iii.romulus.meridian&hl=zh_HK). I need to set a repeat current media function . The steps to set the function is:

1. Open any video file.
2. Slide down to show panel.
3. Tap repeat button to set repeat mode as repeat current media.

I don't know how to implement step 2,3. Any suggestion? Thanks